# Why does potential drop exist?

Tags: electric-current, voltage

I'm sorry that the question is likely to sound stupid but I just can't seem to be able to wrap my head around it.

I think I am a bit comfortable with the mathematical idea of it but I still can't seem to wrap my head around it. I understand that in moving from the point of lower potential to the point of higher potential, the electrons in a solid conductor are continually accelerated by the electric field but also keep losing this energy in the form of heat to the conductor (and hence to the surroundings).

What I don't understand is the fact that more energy is dissipated within a resistor of length *l* than would be dissipated in a wire of length *l*. It just doesn't make sense.

I understand the collisions should change the direction of the electrons to any random direction but the thing is that there is a general movement to the source of higher potential and the kinetic energy of the electrons is increased by the distance it travelled from the start of the resistor to the end of it (and hence, the amount of energy it lost in the resistor should be a function of the distance it travelled within the resistor, independent of resistivity).

If the collisions are more frequent within the resistor, that means that the mean time to a collision is lower. That simply means that the electron travelled less distance before another collision and that means that while it lost energy more frequently, it also lost a proportionately less amount of energy.

Of course this doesn't make sense because I have been to my school's physics lab and I know how hot the resistors can get. But after two days of pondering and googling I still can't seem to find a reasonable explanation for why I'm wrong. I understand that this likely sounds silly and I apologize for that, and I sincerely thank anybody who takes their time to answer this silly question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dissipation in a resistor or wire of the same length $\ell$ doesn't have very much to do with the length - it has to do with the resistance.

For a given current (number of electrons per second crossing a particular point), there will be a voltage drop associated with a given resistance - this is Ohm's law.

A nice intuitive way to think about this is with a bundle of very thin wires. Each wire is so thin that it has quite high resistance; but thousands of these wires in parallel look like a low resistance wire.

If I have that bundle of wires with a certain voltage V across it, and a (low) resistance $R_w$, then we will get a rather large current. Many electrons travel the wire per second, and each of them loses a little bit of energy. But because there are many electrons, the total energy lost is quite large.

Now if I look at just one strand of the bundle, I have a resistor. If I had 1000 strands in the bundle above, then the one strand carries 1/1000th of the current - and 1/1000th of the energy is dissipated since the voltage difference is the same but there are 1000x fewer electrons in this one strand than in the entire bundle.

Does that clear it up for you?

Comment: Thank you! While your answer itself didn't resolve my confusion, that's because of my fault in not being able to state my question correctly. But your intuitive example actually led me to think for a while and it turns out that i didn't quite understand ohm's law. I think i understand it now and i will try to update the question more properly and with what i arrived at once i get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand is the fact that more energy is dissipated within a resistor of length l than would be dissipated in a wire of length l. It just doesn't make sense.

You mean, why is it not like this:

- Electron goes through a resistor while there's a 1 V voltage between the resistor ends -> resistor is heated by energy of 1 V * 1 elementary charge.
- Electron goes through a wire while there's a 1 V voltage between the wire ends ->  the wire is heated by energy of 1 V * 1 elementary charge.

Well actually that's how it is.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer made me stop constantly focusing on this part and to help me figure it out. But my apologies that i will have to select Floris's answer as correct.

Comment: Note that the wire (lower resistance) has many more electrons flowing through it and therefore will hear more when the same voltage is applied. But yes- per electron the heating is the same.